# ReactJS two way binding not working, somewhere wrong with binding

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, reactjs, object

I'm new to *reactJs*, I'm not sure where it went wrong.

I suppose there is something wrong with binding input. I suppose, cant change input because of `value={detail.name}`. However, even though I have deleted `value={detail.name}`,  `Name: {detail.name}` still keeps the original value.

Could somebody give me a hint?

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "./App.css";

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      details: [
        { id: 1, name: "Tom", age: "20" },
        { id: 2, name: "zhunan", age: "22" },
        { id: 3, name: "kobe", age: "35" }
      ]
    };
  }

  changeName(event) {
    this.setState({
      name: event.target.value
    });
  }

  onDelete() {}

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <ul>
          {this.state.details.map((detail, index) => (
            <li key={index}>
              Name: {detail.name} | age: {detail.age}
              <input
                style={{ marginLeft: "10px" }}
                type="text"
                onChange={this.changeName.bind(this)}
                value={detail.name}
              />
            </li>
          ))}
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: what are you trying to do?

Comment: I'm trying to input a value so that Name and age will change accordingly, I have tried to changed input, But Name and age will stays same, I cant upload a pic since i'm not allowed sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I updated the code a bit.
First of all, I moved the binding of the callback to the constructor (to have ONE callback instead of one per item*render)

I also changed the key used in the map to be the id, rather than the index of the current item.

Try, it, I hope it works for you.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "./App.css";

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      details: [
        { id: 1, name: "Tom", age: "20" },
        { id: 2, name: "zhunan", age: "22" },
        { id: 3, name: "kobe", age: "35" }
      ]
    };

    this.changeName = this.changeName.bind(this);
  }

  changeName(event) {
    const {target} = event;
    const id = Number(target.dataset.id);
    const { details } = this.state;
    this.setState({
      details: details.map((detail) => {
        if (detail.id === id) {
          return {
            ...detail,
            name: target.value,
          }
        }
        return detail;
      }),
    });
  }

  onDelete() {}

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <ul>
          {this.state.details.map(({ id, age, name }) => (
            <li key={id}>
              Name: {name} | age: {age}
              <input
                style={{ marginLeft: "10px" }}
                type="text"
                onChange={this.changeName}
                data-id={id}
                value={name}
              />
            </li>
          ))}
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine, nothing wrong with the input data binding. The problem is you're setting the `name` property directly to the state object. That would make it go from this:

```js
this.state = {
details: [
    { id: 1, name: "Tom", age: "20" },
    { id: 2, name: "zhunan", age: "22" },
    { id: 3, name: "kobe", age: "35" }
  ]
}
```

To this:

```js
this.state = {
details: [
    { id: 1, name: "Tom", age: "20" },
    { id: 2, name: "zhunan", age: "22" },
    { id: 3, name: "kobe", age: "35" }
  ],
  name: "Bob"
}
```

Which has no effect on how the component gets rendered. To properly change the name of one of the details, which is what I assume you want, you also need to do a find that detail object to modify. Like this:

```js
changeName(e, target_detail) {
  this.setState({
    // always update the WHOLE STATE OBJECT! using a map
    details: this.state.details.map(detail => {
        // the detail we want to modify has the same ID
        if(detail.id === target_detail.id) {
          // modify the name value of only that 
          target_detail.name = e.target.value

        }
    })
  });
}
```

render method:

```js
render() {
  return (
    <div>
      <ul>
        {this.state.details.map((detail, index) => (
          <li key={index}>
            Name: {detail.name} | age: {detail.age}
            <input
              style={{ marginLeft: "10px" }}
              type="text"
              // arrow functions implicitly "bind" the current this context:
              onChange={e => this.changeName(e, detail)}
              value={detail.name}
            />
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}
```